# NumPy: Average overlapping matricies?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose you have a matrix of shape `(n, m)`.

Further, you have `k` smaller matrices of shape `(s, m)`.

These `k` matrices might have been produced by sharding the larger matrix with something like:

```
stride = z
ranges = [] # will contain sub lists of start / end positions
for i in range(0, n, stride):
    if i + s > n:
        ranges.append([n-s, n]) #<-- if not evenly divisible include last ragged bit
        break
    else:
        ranges.append([i, i+s])

# k = len(ranges)

for a, b in ranges:
    submat = mat[a:b] # <--- produces submats of shape (s, m)
    # not necessarily where submats come from, just for 
    # simple example purpose, feel free to add random noise to each submat
```

How would one, in numpy, join these `k` overlapping submatrices, averaging the overlapping regions?

The goal is to then take these submats and reform the original mat, e.g. something like:

```
blank = np.zeros((n, m))
for i in range(len(submats)):
    a, b = ranges[i]
    blank[a:b] += submats[i] #<--- doesn't account for different amounts of overlapping regions
```

concrete numbers:

```
n = 693
m = 10
# so mat has shape (693, 10)

s = 500
stride = 50

ranges = [[0, 500], [50, 550], [100, 600], [150, 650], [193, 693]]
# notice that the range (0,50) doesn't need to be averaged

k = 5 # len(ranges)

# so we have k submats of shape (500, 10)
```

I currently am doing this:

```
def count_overlap(max_len, ranges): # from example 693, and [[0, 500], ...]
    tally = np.zeros(max_len)
    for i in range(max_len):
        for a, b in ranges:
            if a <= i and i < b:
                tally[i] += 1
    return tally


olap = count_overlap(693, ranges)
olap[:55]
# ([1., 1., ..., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.])
olap[-50:]
# ([2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 1., 1., ..., 1., 1., 1.])
```

to know how much to divide each index of the mat

Comment: @Divakar as in post, yes, they are all `(s, m)`

Comment: @Divakar the same shape as the starting mat `(n, m)`

Comment: @Divakar no. You want to recreate a `(n,m)` matrix from `k`, `(s, m)` matrices, where there is overlap amongst the `k` matrices in the first dimension

Comment: Typically how many ranges you might have? If it's a small number, slicing and adding inside a loop makes sense, as you already have.

Comment: @Divakar I updated the question to provide some concrete examples, `k` will generally be < 100. The issues is uneven amount of overlap

Comment: Also, would the start and end indices have the same difference across all ranges? Like you have 500 in the given sample?

Comment: @Divakar yes, every `k` submatric has the same shape of `(s, m)`, in this case `s=500`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you create the submatrices by slicing the large one, they will have the same values where they overlap, so averaging seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @PaulPanzer the matrices are not directly created from the larger one, that was just an example. If it helps, imagine each submat gets random noise added to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method using bincount + cumsum to count the overlap row-by-row:

Update: added another method which uses only slicing. I expect this to be faster typically.

```
import numpy as np

n = 693
m = 10
# so mat has shape (693, 10)

s = 500
stride = 50

ranges = [[0, 500], [50, 550], [100, 600], [150, 650], [193, 693]]
# notice that the range (0,50) doesn't need to be averaged

k = 5 # len(ranges)

mat = np.random.randint(0,10,(n,m))
submats = []
for a, b in ranges:
    submats.append(mat[a:b])


ranges = np.asarray(ranges)
out = np.zeros((n,m))
# put a 1 at every start and a -1 at every stop
# then take the cumsum this will assign to each row the
# number of intervals it is in
# finally, take the reciprocal
weight = 1 / np.subtract(*map(np.bincount,ranges.T,(None,None),(n+1,n+1))).cumsum()[:n,None]
for sm,(a,b) in zip(submats,ranges):
    out[a:b] += weight[a:b] * sm


# method 2

# sort range ends
ro = ranges.ravel().argsort(kind='stable')
# put 1 for starting and -1 for ending, take cumsum
cnts = (1-((ro&1)<<1)).cumsum()
out = np.zeros((n,m))
# add slices
for sm,(a,b) in zip(submats,ranges):
    out[a:b] += sm
rs = ranges.ravel()[ro]
# divide by overlap
for a,b,c in zip(rs[:-1],rs[1:],cnts[:-1]):
    out[a:b] /= c
```

Comment: I came across an equivalent, although less elegant solution :P Thank you for the help. Except there is exactly one index in our methods which are different... `-43`  (you will have to call `(1 / overlap)`)I am not so familiar with what you did so I need to figure out which is correct

Comment: @SumNeuron With the unmodified slices for submatrices, the stitched version `out` should up to roundoff be the same as `mat`. Maybe you could use this as a quick test.

Comment: sorry `np.where(weight.flatten() != (1/olap))` result in `(array([500, 550, 600, 650]),)` so either I am double counting the edges of bins or the bin method is. I don't quite follow what you mean that `out` "should up  to roundoff..."

Comment: Sorry, my method overcounts the ends I think :P with `<=b`

Comment: @SumNeuron I meant `np.allclose(mat,out)` should return `True` for the example. Also, I've added another method which I think should be faster. Be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

While in my own question I provided an alternative (and less elegant) method I am not attempting to answer my own question. Rather, I am simply wrapping relevant functions and solutions for other to play with:

## Helpers

```py
def shard_rng(maxlen, sublen, stride):
    ranges = [] 
    for i in range(0, maxlen, stride):
        if i + sublen > maxlen:
            ranges.append([maxlen-sublen, maxlen])
            break
        else:
            ranges.append([i, i+sublen])
    return ranges
```

```py
# for testing. stitched_mat - mat should be 1
def split_mat(mat, ranges):
    submats = []
    for a,b in ranges:
        submats.append(mat[a:b] + 1)
    return submats
```

```py
# part of solution 1
def weight_rngs(ranges):
    n = ranges[-1][-1]
    bins = map(np.bincount,np.array(ranges).T,(None,None),(n+1,n+1))
    vals = np.subtract(*bins).cumsum()
    weights = 1 / vals[:n,None]
    return weights
```

## Solutions

Provided by **@Paul Panzer**

```
# solution 1
def stitch_mats(shape, submats, ranges):    
    stitched = np.zeros(shape)
    weights = weight_rngs(ranges)
    for submat, (start, stop) in zip(submats, ranges):
        stitched[start:stop] += weights[start:stop] * submat        
    return stitched
```

```
# solution 2
def stitch_mats2(shape, submats, ranges):
    ranges = np.array(ranges)
    ro = ranges.ravel().argsort(kind='stable')

    # put 1 for starting and -1 for ending, take cumsum
    cnts = (1-((ro&1)<<1)).cumsum()

    stitched = np.zeros((n,m))
    # add slices
    for submat, (start, stop) in zip(submats,ranges):
        stitched[start:stop] += submat

    rs = ranges.ravel()[ro]
    # divide by overlap
    for start, stop, count in zip(rs[:-1],rs[1:],cnts[:-1]):
        stitched[start:stop] /= count
    return stitched
```

## Test

```py
n = 693
m = 10
s = 500 # sublen
stride = 50

mat = np.random.randint(0,10,(n,m))
ranges = shard_rng(n, s, stride)
submats = split_mat(mat, ranges)


stitched_1 = stitch_mats(mat.shape, submats, ranges)
stitched_2 = stitch_mats2(mat.shape, submats, ranges)

np.unique(stitched_1-mat-1.), np.unique(stitched_2-mat-1.)
# array([-8.8817842e-16,  0.0000000e+00,  4.4408921e-16,  8.8817842e-16]), array([0.])
```